# How to deliver a file using command line in Serena Dimensions

Tags: repository, serena

I am trying to deliver a file to a stream in Serena Dimensions. I use following command to deliver files
 but it gives me an error. Can someone help me to figure out what’s the problem here?

```
dmcli-user samm -pass abc123 -host 127.0.0.1 dbname TAM_CM -dsn DIM11 -cmd “DELIVER /WORKSET=“””FE:SA_P1””” /ADD /USER_DIRECTORY=“C:\repo\” /PART=S_DE /COMMENT=“Adding initial files”
```

Comment: Can you please share the error and version of the serena dimension that you are using

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I found the reason for this problem. That is, I wasn’t using the escape character in the comment which is a string with spaces. Also need to mention folder using /DIR parameter. Theses two solved my problem.